# Using tilde (~) in a dynamically created link

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I'm creating sub-menu items with links and URLs dynamically using JavaScript. However, when I navigate to the links the URL doesn't parse the `~` as the root directory but just appends the string to the current URL.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>

        <div id="left-menu" class="sidr-hide">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="~/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="~/ListItem1">ListItem1</a></li>
                <li><a href="~/ListItem2">ListItem1</a>
                    <ul id="ListItemDropdown">
Following items will be created Dynamically

       @* <li><a href="~/ListItem2/?param=SubItem1">SubItem1</a></li>
        <li><a href="~/ListItem2/?param=SubItem2">SubItem2</a></li>*@
        </ul>
                </li>

            Added here for link testing: 
                <li><a href="~/ListItem2/?param=SubItem1">SubItem1</a></li>
                <li><a href="~/ListItem2/?param=SubItem2">SubItem2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <script src="~/Scripts/Layout.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

All links that are written directly in HTML tags above work fine.

JavaScript:

```javascript
var ExchangeLeftDropdown = document.getElementById("ListItemDropdown");

$(document).ready(function () {
var test = "Subitem1}SubItem2}"; //This string will be filled by a controller later on
var test2 = test.split("}");
for (i = 0; i < test2.length; i++) {
     //Create List Item
    var newListItem = document.createElement("li");
     //Create Link Item
    var itemLink = document.createElement("a");
    //Add text to link Item
    itemLink.textContent = test2[i];
    //Add link URL to link Item
    itemLink.setAttribute("href", "~/ListItem2/?dom=" + test2[i]);//Desired URL, 
    //but this tilde doesn't equate to home directory, so instead I get this 
    //in the URL http://localhost:1461/'DirectoryCurrentlyViewing'/~/ListItem2/?dom=SubItem2. 
    //it does lead to the right place if you navigate from the home directory


   // itemLink.setAttribute("href", "<%=ResolveUrl(~/Exchange/?dom=" + test2[i] + ")%>"); 
    // This attempt resulted in me getting a 404 error vs a Server Error in '/' Application
    //The URl is again a directly pasted string: http://localhost:1461/ListItem2/<%=ResolveUrl(~/ListItem2/?dom=SubItem2)%%>
    itemLink.setAttribute("runat", "server"); //The attempt to parse the URL server side didn't have any effect
    newListItem.appendChild(itemLink);
    ExchangeLeftDropdown.appendChild(newListItem);
}
});
```

Is there any property in the link creation I can change/add or text to insert into the link creation that will allow the site to parse the `~` as the root directory?

Comment: It looks like you're confusing [ASP.NET's `~` in paths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx) for something that can be used in HTML in general. If you want root-relative urls, just use root relative URLs and leave off the `~`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A path starting with a `~` tilde character has a special meaning in some tools. However, this is not the case in URLs. The `~` tilde has no special meaning, so your URL is interpreted as a normal relative URL. If you're on `http://example.com/a/b` and you click a link to `~c`, you'll end up in `http://example.com/a/~c` instead of `http://example.com/~c`.

If you would like your URLs to be interpreted as absolute paths under your hostname, instead of relative URLs, they need to begin with `/` instead. This is called a ["path-absolute URL"](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#syntax-url-path-absolute). If the `~` is supposed to be present in the final URL, such as for a Linux user directory, you may want `/~`. If `~` is just supposed to be a stand-in for the host root, just use `/` on its own:

```
itemLink.setAttribute("href", "/ListItem2/?dom=" + test2[i]);//Desired URL,
```

If the site's root is not at the host root, but is in a subdirectory, there is no standard URL syntax to do what you want. It wouldn't be possible: the browser has no way of knowing the site structure defined on your server.

Answer (score -1):

The tilde has no meaning in javascript.  Try using:

```
var hostname = window.location.href;
itemLink.setAttribute("href", hostname + "/ListItem2/?dom=" + test2[i]);
```